# Artifactory: Uploaded artifacts do not have a md5 and sha1 file anymore

Tags: maven, repository, artifactory, sha1

After we updated JFrog Artifactory we realised that all uploaded artifacts could be uploaded with related .pom file.

But usually the maven-directory contained 4 files:
 1. Our uploaded .jar/.war file
 2. related .pom file
 3. .sha1 file 
 4. .md5 file

3. and 4. are missing now.
   Is there any setting I've overseen? all documentation from JFrog tells me, it should be generated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

These files are sort of "phantom" files. They don't show up in the directory, but if you request them using the REST API you'll get the expected response. For any existing file `foo.bar`, requesting `foo.bar.md5`, `foo.bar.sha1`, or `foo.bar.sha256` will provide the appropriate checksum, even though those files don't actually exist.

I think this makes more sense than autogenerating these files for every artifact. Since they do exist for every artifact in every repository, they don't actually provide useful information in the UI, so it just becomes needless clutter.

Comment: you are right, I could also download it, even there are not there. They are really "phantom"-files. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory started 'hiding' these files as part of [RTFACT-6962](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-6962) where they were deemed mostly unnecessary since only a handful of legacy clients even care about them (i.e. old maven which also uses the browsing api they appear in) .

If they matter to you they can be 'brought back' by adding the property `artifactory.ui.hideChecksums=false` to your [`system.properties`](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Configuration+Files#ConfigurationFiles-SystemProperties) file.

As @DarthFennec mentioned these are not actually files, rather they are checksum string that are generated from the artifact's checksum each time you trigger the `.md5` `.sha1` or `.sha2` endpoints for a certain path.